# Objective C geoLocation method doesn't return double value automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, geolocation

Im building a small application that reads some data from a webserver, and that works finde. I have then made a method which is a void, and only gets latitude and longitude from some adress.

```
-(void)getLocation{



if (!self.geocoder) {
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}


NSString *address = self.label1.text;



[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {



    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

        latitude1 = coordinate.latitude;
        longitude1 = coordinate.longitude;

    }

}];
}
```

in the .h file i have declared these to variables (not in the interface):

```
@property double latitude1;
@property double longitude1;
```

i then call this with a button:

```
 - (IBAction)find:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"Latitude1: %f og Longitude1: %f", latitude1, longitude1);


float spanX = 0.00725;
float spanY = 0.00725;
MKCoordinateRegion region;

region.center.latitude = self.latitude1;
region.center.longitude = self.longitude1;

region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

This works perfectly fine....

but i just cannot call this:

```
    NSLog(@"Latitude: %f and %f",latitude1, longitude1 );
```

from the viewDidLoad method.

Its like i have to use it in an IBaction, and that I can not use latitude1 and longitude1 in any other way. What i need is to take the latitude and longitude and be able to use the values how i want, and not only by pushing a button.

it just doesn't make sense, that it works if i manually push my update button, then it shows things on the map and displays latitude and longitude, but when i use it in the viewdidload method, it just displays 0.00000.

another thing i have been thinking about is how to return multiple values from one method, like i want to return latitude1 and longitude1 from my getLocation method. nsdictionary or array or struct?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code isn't complete, but here's my advice.

Set a breakpoint on this link of code:

```
        if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
```

If the GEOCODER block fails, you'll have 0 for location.

Comment: this is what is returned: latitude1 double 0 0
longitude1 double 0 0

Comment: so it seems like at the break point the block doesn't get anything from the geoCoder

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your viewDidLoad, you haven't successfully geocoded a location yet. The `geocodeAddressString` method is asynchronous. You call it and it returns immediately. Then, some time in the future, your completion block gets called.

It has to wait because the geocoding process connects to a remote server over your network connection.

If your view controller's viewDidLoad method is called before the geocode call has finished, your latitude and longitude variables won't be set yet.

I suggest you add a boolean instance variable, "geocodingComplete". Set it to TRUE in your completion handler. Then you'll be able to tell if you have a valid address geocoded or not.

Comment: where should the boolean be added?